# Flex grow 1 doesn't allow proper scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox

I'm running into, what I think is, a tiny issue with flex. I'm trying to get a simple layout (as shown in the linked jsfiddle). However, when the div on the right (in color red) overflows in its height, the element overflows in the viewport and is only scrollable when it overflows the height of the viewport.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MZein/tfrakgb0/)

I'm pretty sure it's because I'm using `height: 100%;` in a lot of elements, but I need them to be as big as they can be (to fill the viewport height completely).

What I want is the viewport to be completely filled by these three sections: nav, left side-bar, and right content (see the following image). Where the right content section should be scrollable when it overflows the viewport.

[image: What I want]

So, to come to a conclusion.. The issue here is that the scrollable content first overflows the viewport and when the div is (what it seems like) the same height as the viewport, it starts being scrollable. I obviously want the div to be scrollable when it overflows the viewport.

What's wrong and what I want is basically described in the following image. [image: Left: what's wrong. Right: What I want]

How would I achieve this? Thanks for your time.

### Code (that is also available in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MZein/tfrakgb0/))

**HTML**

```
  <div id="content-container">
    <div id="content">
      <div id="left">
        IM LEFT
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        <div id="inner">
          IM RIGHT
        </div>
        IM RIGHT
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main {
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#main nav {
  background: orange;

  width: 100%;
  height: 96px;
}

#main #content-container {
  background: darkgreen;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#main #content-container #content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#main #content-container #content #left {
  background: darkblue;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
}

#main #content-container #content #right {
  background: darkred;
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#main #content-container #content #right #inner {
  font-size: 25rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code like below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  height: 100vh; /*full height*/
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#main nav {
  background: orange;
  height: 96px; /*fixed height*/
}

#content-container {
  background: darkgreen;
  color: white;
  flex-grow: 1; /*fill the remaining height*/
  min-height:0;  /*enable the shrink*/
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

#left {
  background: darkblue;
  width: 30%;
}

#right {
  background: darkred;
  overflow:auto;
}


/*Irrelevant*/
#inner {
  font-size: 25rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/games">Games</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/create">Create</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="content-container">
    <div id="content">
      <div id="left">
        IM LEFT
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        <div id="inner">
          IM RIGHT
        </div>
        IM RIGHT
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! Could you please be so kind as to add a little description to your answer, so other people can easily understand why this works?

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main {
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#main nav {
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: 96px;
}

#main #content-container {
  background: darkgreen;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 96px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 96px);
}

#main #content-container #content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#main #content-container #content #left {
  background: darkblue;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
}

#main #content-container #content #right {
  background: darkred;
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
}

#main #content-container #content #right {
  font-size: 27em;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/games">Games</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/create">Create</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="content-container">
    <div id="content">
      <div id="left">
        IM LEFT
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        IM RIGHT
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Seriously? You totally changed your answered and just copied mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55753888/2735479
(But now it works at least ^^ )

Comment: @Tim Krief Dear Tim. At first I did not understand the essence of the question. And my native language is different. I did not copy you. Property Calc know everything. I am an engineer. And I do not always understand the questions in another language from the first time. From time to time, I help. But, you did not notice other problems that I have already fixed.

Comment: It was just a joke, I clearly saw that your answer was different, but at the end you used the same method. But, your answer should give more explanation and context, not just raw code. Plus, I noticed the other "issues" you fixed, for instance, word-break. But these "issues" are not part of the OP question. Finally, I think there is a more elegant way to fix OP's issue yet to be found.

Comment: @Tim Krief I gave a hint, the desired aesthetics - make the owner himself. I enjoy people with a friendly attitude. I will vote for you. You can find me, if you want, on the social network vk.com, my page is listed in my profile here. If I offended you, I beg you - do not be offended at me.

Comment: The answer seems good, but, as I said in Tim Krief's answer, I don't want to define a specific height for the navbar.

Answer (score -1):

One solution could be to take the height of the nav element into account when defining the height of your `#content` using `calc(100% - 96px)`, `96px` being the height of your nav element:

```
#main #content-container #content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: calc(100% - 96px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 96px);
}
```

Comment: Seems like a good fix, but I don't want to define a specific height for my navbar

Answer (score -1):

```
#main #content-container #content #right {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: This may not work because the element is bigger than it should be anyway.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.